# Gear icon in reputation block of the profile is broken

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

One picture replaces hundred words:

> [image: rep-gear]

Comment: @Arulkumar tagged [tag:status-completed]. I will wait until it actually fixed.

Comment: Looks like the issue has been solved now.